# My string has turned into an array of letters

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, string

I've pulled data from a database. But when I echo a specific value from within the array, the string is shown as an array, with each letter separated with its own index!

I've tried implode but got an error that the arguments I passed are not correct, and explode does not change a thing.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cours WHERE date = :date AND time = :time AND cours = :cours AND present ='non'");
 $stmt->execute([':date' => $date, ':cours' => $cours, ':time' => $time]);

 if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $output = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $classe = $output[0]['classe'];
        // explode(",",$classe);
        // implode(",",$classe);
        echo json_encode($classe);

 } else {
    $errors = "No data found for this date";
    echo json_encode($errors);
 }
```

The result in the console is

```
[object Array]: ["W", "i", "n", "t", "e", "r", " ", "2", "0", "1", "9"]
0: "W"
1: "i"
2: "n"
3: "t"
4: "e"
5: "r"
6: " "
7: "2"
8: "0"
9: "1"
10: "9"
length: "11"
```

You can see the result I get in the console log above. What I need is to have that as one value, in string format.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. If I take the array and do `echo implode($array);` I get `Winter 2019`. Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it directly in the query (with `GROUP_CONCAT()`), but if you want a PHP solution, just `implode()` without a delimiter it before you encode it.

Though `fetchAll()` seems rather pointless when you only use the first row? You can do `$output = $stmt->fetch();` and then just `$classe = $output['classe'];` (or even use `fetchColumn()` if you alter the query to only return the `classe` column).

```
if ($output = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
    $classe = $output[0]['classe'];
    // explode(",",$classe);
    $classe = implode("", $classe);
    echo json_encode($classe);
} else {
    $errors = "No data found for this date";
    echo json_encode($errors);
}
```

By using `GROUP_CONCAT()` you would do it all in the query,

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(classe SEPARATOR '') as allClasse FROM cours WHERE date = :date AND time = :time AND cours = :cours AND present ='non'");
$stmt->execute([':date' => $date, ':cours' => $cours, ':time' => $time]);

if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo json_encode($row['allClasse']);
} else {
    $errors = "No data found for this date";
    echo json_encode($errors);
}
```

Comment: Just as a little side not: If you do not need a special `glue` for the implode, you can just do `implode($classe);`.

Comment: Indeed you can! Though my personal preference is to be explicit about it - but you're absolutely right, you can do `$classe = implode($classe)`! It's documented in the signature in the manual of that function: https://php.net/implode

Comment: There will be more rows, I'll be using a for loop. But now I'm just trying to set the variables I want to pull from each array and I came across my problem.

Comment: Using the two implode methods mentioned just above… $classe = implode($classe); I get the Following error

Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array

Comment: I believe it recognizes $classe as a string, maybe untim it goes through the json_encode, but I cannot get rid of that without a different error message...

Comment: Then `$classe` is not an array - which of course its not.. Its the actual column (of which I don't know the value). Could you maybe tell me what `var_dump($classe);` is, just after `fetchAll()`?

Comment: vardump error message! 

error: Object
text: "<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'> <small>C:\laragon\www\Attendance App\myApp\src\app\api\updateAbsenceDb.php:51:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Winter 2019'</font> <i>(length=11)</i> </pre>"

Comment: Then you probably just need to `echo json_encode($classe);`  without imploding it? It's got the right value, "Winter 2019"?

Comment: `string` `Winter 2019` `length=11` could you try to just `echo $classes;` without the json encode ?

Comment: echo json_encode($classe); is what I started with. That's what gives me the array.

Comment: That wouldn't be an array, so you must be doing something else. `$output[0]['classe']` is the exact column `classe` of the first row, that cannot be an array - it MUST be a string.

Comment: echo $classes;  with the json code gives me the Following error…

error: Object
description: "JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:1"

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing between `$classe = $output[0]['classe'];` and `echo json_encode($classe);` in your real code ?

Comment: @Qirel It is a string, yes, which is why the implode function doesn't like it as an argument.  Somewhere between that point and the console log, it is being converted to an array.

Comment: @Frankich .  I'm positive. I've tried the suggestions here, but now have reverted the code back to exactly as you see it at the top of this page.

Comment: `echo json_encode($string)` doesn't make it an array. Remove the implode, and just print it directly - encoded it just becomes quoted. `json_encode()` is used to convert arrays to JSON objects, which would be useful if you use `echo json_encode($output);`

Comment: Okay. Well I'm going to attack it from a different angle. I'll send through the objects as a whole, then work at Breaking them up and declaring my variables from the Ionic/Angular side of things. Thanks you all for your input.